# Why is std::function implemented as a partial template specialisation with an empty base declaration?

Tags: c++, templates, std-function, partial-specialization

Consider the declarations for `std::function`:

```cpp
template< class >
class function; /* undefined */

template< class R, class... Args >
class function<R(Args...)>;
```

[[source: cppreference.com]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

We have a non-specialised declaration of the template that declares an empty structure, followed by a (*partial?*) specialisation, but unlike partial specialisations that I have normally seen, this one only uses types declared in its template arguments (doesn't hard-code any types). Its purpose appears to be so that when `std::function` is instantiated like:

```cpp
std::function<float(int, int)>
```

Then `R` gets the return type (`float`) and `(int, int)` goes into the parameter pack `Args...`.

When implementing my own memoisation class as an exercise, I found I had to provide an identical template interface as `std::function`'s to get my memoisation class to work, as it wraps a `std::function` object but I likewise need access to the return type and arguments so I can forward to the wrapped function using the function-call operator:

```cpp
template <class>
class memoiser;

template <class R, class... Args>
class memoiser<R(Args...)> {
    memoiser(std::function<R(Args...)>);
    R operator()(Args... args);
}
```

I noticed that attempting to remove the first declaration causes the second to not compile, and without it being done this way, the only alternative is:

```cpp
template <class R, class... Args>
class memoiser { ... }
```

But that's not right as then, `memoiser` has to be instantiated as `memoiser<float, int, int>` rather than `memoiser<float(int, int)>`, this is unidiomatic and doesn't work when a free function is passed in via `decltype` (whereas the *working* version does).

But what exactly is going on here? I know the second partial specialisation that works seems to be required to correctly map a function type to the template parameters, but what exact feature of the language is being used to facilitate this? Is it possible to construct other custom exact mappings of more complicated constructs cleanly into template arguments in this way?:

Why is the empty non-specialised template declaration required?

```cpp
template <class>
class triple;

template <class X, class Y, class Z>
class triple<std::tuple<X, Y, Z>> {}; // can use this to extract X,Y,Z from the tuple instantiated with

...

triple<std::tuple<int, float, char>> butternuts = {};
```

Comment: That's just how class templates work. First one needs to declare or define general case and then implement specializations. Otherwise compiler doesn't know what you are doing. It doesn't work this way with functions, as they have different declaration properties - there are no partial specializations but one can declare multiple functions with the same name.

Comment: I understand, I suppose my point was it's a bit surprising because normally with specialisations, you have a implementation for the default version, whereas `std:: function` doesn't, the specialisation seems only to exist so it can extract from the template argument the parts it needs for the function signature

Comment: Well, one could potentially declare the original template with more parameters, some of which are defaulted. So there is a purpose in declaring it, as it specifies general format of the template. This is also fairly normal in case one wants to make a class with restricted templare parameters (at least prior to C++20 and concepts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is to support the fancy or idiomatic syntax `std::function<float(int, int)>`,

and effectively prevent the other possible syntax `std::function<float, int, int>` (because I think you can't specialize something from `std::`).

`std::function` is probably based on Boost.Function, and at the time, some compilers were confused by the fancy syntax.
So Boost.Function provides both options and calls the second "Portable" syntax.

> Preferred syntax: `boost::function<float (int x, int y)> f;`
>
> Portable syntax: `boost::function2<float, int, int> f;`

See here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/function/tutorial.html#idp241211680

Besides being more idiomatic, it could be that at the time, it was also even easier to implement it this way when your only option was to manually program all the cases with different numbers of input parameters, and there were no variadic templates.

As for what feature of the language is being used, I would say 1) template specialization and 2) functions have well-defined types in the language.
`float(int, int)` is a concrete type, probably one that you cannot  instantiate,
but in the same way that `float(*)(int, int)` is also a concrete type, a concrete pointer-to-function type or that `float(&)(int, int)` is a reference-to function type.